# NSTextField Clear Button

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield

On the iPhone a `UITextField` can have a clearButtonMode set to show a small clear button (X) at the end of a text input. Similarly, on the Mac the `NSSearchField` has a nice clear button on it at the end. My question is - is there a way to enable this on a normal `NSTextField`?

Comment: Why do you want this? This isn't normal for non-search text fields on the Mac.

Comment: An example: You use the textField for input from the user,and will be changed on the fly by the user. The textfield is also inside a scrollView because size is an issue. For the user to clear the text, they would need to use Command+a keys and then backspace key. Having a button saves all the keystrokes.

Comment: Why would you put a text field inside a scroll view? Text fields are for short pieces of text, usually only single lines. If the text may be so long that the user will need scroll bars, you should use a text view (inside a scroll view) instead.

Comment: I want a quick way for my user to be able to delete the text they've entered into a particular part of my App which, as it so happens, is actually search related. Regardless, I don't see the big deal really. It's a nice, easy, intuitive UI feature and the issue at hand isn't so much 'why'/'when' as 'how'.

Comment: Oops, my bad, I meant it to be NSTextView, not  NSTextField. I always mix them up. Sorry. But as JoeR points out. Its quicker to use a single click to clear the text in both cases.

Comment: @JoeR Almost every question on this site is first subjected to the question "What are you trying to accomplish? Is there a better or more intended solution than the one you ask for?" before anyone answers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's nothing built-in; just use a search field and turn off the magnifying glass:

```
[[button cell] setSearchButtonCell:nil];
```

Comment: `searchField.placeholderString = "";` to remove the default "Search" placeholder.

Comment: For swift use `(searchField.cell as! NSSearchFieldCell).searchButtonCell = nil`

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same thing for a  multi-lined NSTextField the other day, with no luck so ended up using  a button set with no border and to toggle with a small image. set very close to the NSTextField (not on it)

and:

```
- (IBAction)clearTextViewTex:(id)sender{

 [textField performSelector:@selector(selectAll:)];
[textField performSelector:@selector(delete:)];     

}
```

Doing it this way also retained the undo functions, without me having to write any NSUndoManager stuff.